# How to load data from an SQLite Database query into a textbox?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite, combobox, textbox

So I'm making a rota system for a project and I need a textbox to output the contracted hours of the employee that the user currently has selected in the combo box. The problem is, I have no idea how to go about it;

```
    Sub GetContractedHours()

    Dim sSql As String
    Dim newds As New DataSet
    Dim newdt As New DataTable

    sSql = "SELECT emp_contractedhours FROM Employee WHERE emp_fn ='" & cboEmpName.Text & "%'"

    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sSql, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(newds, "Employee")
    newdt = newds.Tables(0)

    txtUserAlertHours.DataSource = newdt
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any of that code. Just get all the data in the first place and then bind your `ComboBox` and your `TextBox`, e.g.

```
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim conection As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT emp_fn, emp_contractedhours FROM Employee", connection)

adapter.Fill(table)

cboEmpName.DisplayMember = "emp_fn"
cboEmpName.DataSource = table

txtUserAlertHours.DataBindings.Add("Text", table, "emp_contractedhours")
```

The `TextBox` will then be automatically populated when you make a selection in the `ComboBox`. That's how data-binding works.

If you do want to query the database each time then you shouldn't use a data adapter at all.  You're only retrieving one value and that's exactly what `ExecuteScalar` is for. Create a command with the appropriate SQL, call `ExecuteScalar` and assign the result to the `Text` of your `TextBox`.

If you really did want to use data-binding with the code you have (which would be silly) then you can bind just as I have demonstrated above.  Just note that, if you're going to use a different `DataTable` each time, you need to remove the old binding first.  You can do that most easily by calling `Clear` on the `DataBindings` collection, assuming you have not bound any other properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I needed, very appreciated